# Why was my post edited for "spam"?

Tags: discussion, support, self-promotion

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow) self-promotion is okay if **all** of the following apply:

> - you paraphrase the content of the linked item (possibly omitting details or examples)
> - you identify the author (yourself, MSDN, etc)
> - someone could benefit from the answer without reading the linked item at all
> - you include information to let the reader decide if clicking the link is worthwhile

I posted an answer which met all of the above criteria and also included a relevant link to a course I did. My answer was subsequently edited by someone else to remove the link.

I don't mind if self-promotion is clearly disallowed, but as far as I can tell, what I did was allowed or else I wouldn't have done it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Is the content being promoted relevant to the question? No? Then leave it out.

Comment: Yes, it is completely relevant.

Comment: Since it's behind a paywall, the link is _still_ not useful to the general public. I'd leave it out.

Comment: Many self-promoting links are obscure or otherwise not useful to the general public. That can't be the criteria for deciding whether it's spam or not.

Comment: How often did you link to that post? If all of your answers link to your blog, it's not OK even if you disclose your affiliation.

Comment: If it's not useful, don't do it.

Comment: Is there any reason you only added (tried to add) "Feel free to email me if you'd like to discuss in more detail." after the link was removed?

Comment: If it's not useful, leave it out. Period. Further discussions are discussions about the edit description wording. I wouldn't mind - at all - _not_ discussing that.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion

Comment: for anyone wondering:  the answer in question has been subsequently deleted as link-only.

Comment: I understand there are a lot of conflicting opinions on this, but so far nobody has provided a concrete answer based on the written rules of the site.

Comment: Wrong. Nobody provided the answer you want to hear. There is a difference.

Comment: Nobody provided an answer _based on the rules of the site_. I'm getting a lot of opinions, and I respect those, but they don't answer the question.

Comment: I wouldn't call the community disagreeing with you a conflicting opinion.

Comment: The webpage you linked to didn't contain further resources or help that could have been of use to the asker. It was basically self-promotion. You answered a question about programming, then told them to go to a link leading to a website full of **paid** courses to everything from dogma to engineering. And you directly benefitted from that. Theres a difference between linking to a help page for a certain function and linking to a revenue-generating page that is totally unrelated.

Comment: The link was 100% relevant, as others have already acknowledged.

Comment: Just give up already and be glad you didn't receive the -100 rep penalty that posting spam normally brings.

Comment: I didn't receive a penalty because I didn't spam. I followed the rules of the site and my question was edited by one person because he didn't agree with the rules of the site and took matters into his own hands.

Comment: I wrote that bulleted list, and imo mentioning your course should be ok, assuming the answer is meaningful without it. Leading in as you did with "if you have a subscription" also helps. That said, I've never linked to any of my PS courses from a post on SE, not even the PS course on SE :-)

Comment: @KateGregory "assuming the answer is meaningful without it" - now _that's_ the real problem here. One might even argue not only the answer contained nothing of substance but the link, but also the sole purpose of the answer was to post the link.

Answer (score 13):

Lets put it in a simple terms:

### Can the asker solve his problem just by reading the text contained in your answer and nothing else?

*(people call this self-contained answers)*

If they can, just leave the link out, or better yet, just copy over the relevant part of the material (which I presume you *own*) and leave a copy here (note that by doing so you are relicensing your content to Stack Exchange using the cc-by-sa license) and just leave the link as reference.

Comment: Not all information can be copied and pasted. Hence the relevant link.

Comment: @BenPiper Following your link we get [here](http://www.pluralsight.com/signup/?v=a&term=m) I dare to deny the relevance

Comment: @bummi What is the exact URL you went to? The link you reference is not even close to what I posted.

Comment: @Ben I think there is not much to say about it, everyone who enters your page is requested to fund or has at least to register  for a trial. I admit that the[page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow) you've linked unfortunately draws very fuzzy boundaries for the definition of relevant and excessive. To exaggerate it, even a hotline for $ 1.99 per minute could possible be covered(justified) somehow with this definition and that is certainly the last thing we could imagine for SO.

Comment: I think this is the right occasion to sharpen the definitions for people posting answers and for those who are trying to keep the site clean.

Comment: My question still stands: Why was my answer "edited for spam" when it was _clearly and definitively_ *not* spam according to the written rules of the site? No one has been able to answer that objectively.

Answer (score 12):

### I'm the user who removed the spam.

In the answer in question, you linked to *paid content* that **you are profiting from**. Answers must be self-contained, i.e., they can't rely on third-party resources to be helpful. Links to paid content -- because it is unuseful -- are **spam** and **low quality**.

On [another answer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27626563/revisions), you even call it a ***"shameless plug"***, linking to the *same* paid content.

Comment: "Answers must be self-contained, i.e., they can't rely on third-party resources to be helpful." -- this much is true (and very important). "you linked to paid content that you are profiting from. This is the definition of spam." -- hell, no.

Comment: @JanDvorak How so? (I'll update my answer)

Comment: I don't know exactly what @JanDvorak's answer might be, but to me; spam does not really have to be for 'profit'. It's equally spam if someone is promoting their blog, for instance.

Comment: Linking to own commercial material is allowed if disclosed, relevant and useful. Basically, see the meta post linked by OP.

Comment: And I agree with @JanDvorak above, too.

Comment: @AndrewBarber note that promoting one's own blog is for profit as well. Unless it happens to be 100% ad-free (unlikely).

Comment: @JanDvorak Agreed; but I'd take it further, actually. The exposure that links will bring are a sort of 'profit' in a way.

Comment: What if we define the key property of spam is that it is useful to the poster rather than the readers?

Comment: @JanDvorak FWIW Wikipedia says spamming is about ["unsolicited or undesirable electronic messages"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming)

Comment: @gnat in which case... unsolicited - I guess so, check. Undesirable - check. Electronic - check. Message - check.