# Does the question OP have the right to edit an answer to line up with their own ideas?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

A user suggested an [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/34393) to [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246040/202832) on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246036/202832) of theirs.

They removed relevant, useful information from my answer because (presumably) it incriminates them of spamming. Fortunately, because they didn't have [the privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), the edit was rejected by two established users.

Is this behavior acceptable?

If not... What, if anything, could be done to help discourage malicious edits such as these?

Comment: Are you asking if it's okay, or what can be done to stop it? Your title and body disagree.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheElfHat Fixed.

Answer (score 11):

If the user *doesn't* have the privilege to edit, you or two users who *do* have editing privileges will reject the edit.

If the user *has* the privilege to edit, it will go through and you (or anyone else watching, actually) can roll it back if you feel that it's necessary. ( *though I find it rare that users with 2K rep will edit maliciously like that; by the time they get the privilege, they're usually deserving of it, in my experience* )

Why isn't the regular editing system enough?

Answer (score 5):

I think putting the edits in the triage queue is overkill. We have a edit queue already.

Let the community reject that edit or do it yourself. If it was approved already: just roll it back. If you come in an edit war: flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score -1):

I propose that substantial/suspicious edits by users over 2k be added to the **triage queue**. To be considered suspicious, the edit would have to either

- Remove a significant amount of text (>~30%) without adding much (<~5%) or
- Add a significant amount of text (>~100%)

Because of the way the triage queue works, no useful action may be *blocked* (Especially important for the removal of offensive content), but malicious actions will be *peer-reviewed*.